# v-on:click inside a Vue Component does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a simple `Vue` instance for a sidebar in my application where it lists all the menu of the sidebar. I have a local component for the template like so.

```
template:'<div><li class="custom-erp-menu-list" v-on:click="toggleOpenChild">'+
    '<a href="#">'+
        '<span>'+
            '<img src="assets/images/dollar-bills.svg" class="custom-erp-module-list-icon custom-erp-user-icons" width="18" height="18" alt="">'+
        '</span>'+
        '<span class="custom-erp-menu-parent">Purchase Order</span>'+
    '</a>'+
    '<ul class="nav custom-erp-menu-child-dropdown" id="purchase-order-child">'+
        '<li><a href="page-profile.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Profile</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="page-login.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Login</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="page-lockscreen.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Lockscreen</a></li>'+
    '</ul>'+
'</li></div>'
```

There is some weird error which says

> property or method "toggleOpenChild" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

You can check out the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cgxnLajf/) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toggleOpenChild is in the parent wrapper, but your calling in in the child component where it does not exist.

Depending on your structure - you can either move that method into the child component, or tweak and use vue events.

```
    {
      template:
        '<div><li class="custom-erp-menu-list" v-on:click="toggleOpenChild">' +
        '<a href="#">' +
        "<span>" +
        '<img src="" class="custom-erp-module-list-icon custom-erp-user-icons" width="18" height="18" alt="">' +
        "</span>" +
        '<span class="custom-erp-menu-parent">Purchase Order</span>' +
        "</a>" +
        '<ul class="nav custom-erp-menu-child-dropdown" id="purchase-order-child">' +
        '<li><a href="page-profile.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Profile</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="page-login.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Login</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="page-lockscreen.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Lockscreen</a></li>' +
        "</ul>" +
        "</li></div>",
      data: function() {
        return {
          user: []
        };
      },
      methods : {

        // method has to be part of the component
        toggleOpenChild : function()
        {
          console.log('open child');
        }
      }
}
```

adpated from your demo : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePrOqm

Answer (score 1):

Your `toggleOpenChild` should be placed in your component's methods, like this:

```
components: {
  "side-bar-modules": {
    template:
      '<div><li class="custom-erp-menu-list" v-on:click="toggleOpenChild">' +
      '<a href="#">' +
      "<span>" +
      '<img src="assets/images/dollar-bills.svg" class="custom-erp-module-list-icon custom-erp-user-icons" width="18" height="18" alt="">' +
      "</span>" +
      '<span class="custom-erp-menu-parent">Purchase Order</span>' +
      "</a>" +
      '<ul class="nav custom-erp-menu-child-dropdown" id="purchase-order-child">' +
      '<li><a href="page-profile.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Profile</a></li>' +
      '<li><a href="page-login.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Login</a></li>' +
      '<li><a href="page-lockscreen.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Lockscreen</a></li>' +
      "</ul>" +
      "</li></div>",
    data: function() {
      return {
        user: []
      };
    },
    methods: {
      //function to close/open the child elements
      //when the parent menu is clicked.
      toggleOpenChild: function(event) {
        var currentParent = $(event.currentTarget)
          .find(".custom-erp-menu-parent")
          .text();
        var childListID = currentParent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-");
        $(".custom-erp-menu-list > ul")
          .not($("#" + childListID + "-child"))
          .slideUp()
          .removeClass("custom-erp-menu-child-open");
        if ($("#" + childListID + "-child").is(":hidden")) {
          $("#" + childListID + "-child")
            .slideDown(300)
            .toggleClass("custom-erp-menu-child-open");
        } else {
          $("#" + childListID + "-child")
            .slideUp(300)
            .toggleClass("custom-erp-menu-child-open");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cgxnLajf/1/